# Universal Links to Amazon

Tags: ios, ios9, ios-universal-links

Shouldn't we be able to use Universal Links into Amazon on iOS? They are hosting this file: https://www.amazon.com/apple-app-site-association and [this](http://www.jackivers.me/blog/2015/9/17/list-of-universal-link-ios-9-apps) blog post seem to be certain of it. However, if I make a link that follows one of their site-association rules, such as

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0062273205](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0062273205),

I keep getting directed to Safari instead of the app. I have never clicked **Back to X** from the Amazon app, so it can't be that cache that is messing with me.

Answer (score 1):

Universal Links *do* work with the Amazon app on iOS. I tested the example ([http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0062273205](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0062273205)) on iOS 9.2.1, and it opened the app as expected.

Have you have scrolled all the way to the top of the Amazon page? There should be a banner [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUYs7.png) that will forward you to the app. If not, I suppose it's conceivable that your copy of the Amazon app didn't correctly register for Universal Links when first installed. You could try deleting it and reinstalling.

Comment: You are right, the same link seems to work when I try on a different device. I have tried reinstalling, and there is no banner at the top of the page. This is a minor problem since it's only on my device, but I find it interesting.

Comment: I assume Universal Links work on your device for other apps? This is pedantic (and I apologize), but did you delete the app manually prior to reinstalling it?

Comment: Admittedly running short on ideas now...if you paste the link into an app like Notes or iMessage, any difference? I know Safari sometimes handles Universal Links in rather idiosyncratic ways....

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, however I did post an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52756003/how-to-open-amazon-app-from-within-my-app/66192758#66192758) that seems to work currently which might help someone:

I too had mixed results with universal links, it worked on some devices and not on others even though the Amazon app is installed.

In summary, what I did was:

1. Using https://www.appsight.io/app/amazon I was able to get the URL Scheme for the amazon app
2. I whitelisted that URL scheme in my info.Plist
3. I added some code to check if I can open the amazon app using the scheme otherwise I should fallback to using Universal links

Exact code I used is available on my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52756003/how-to-open-amazon-app-from-within-my-app/66192758#66192758) here.