# What is the iOS app URL scheme for Bitmoji app?

Tags: ios, swift, url-scheme

I'm trying to open the Bitmoji app from within my own app in iOS using `UIApplication.shared.open`. When I use just `"https://www.bitmoji.com/"` URL, the Bitmoji app does not intercept the call and it opens the URL in Safari.

Tried `"bitmoji://"` as the URL scheme, but this does not work. Then I googled for the bitmoji app URL scheme, but without success. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `bitmoji-sdk://`:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "bitmoji-sdk://") else { return }
UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```

---

<sup>Taken from [AppSight.io](https://www.appsight.io/app/bitmoji)</sup>

Comment: You're welcome :) BTW you can research stuff like this on sites like [AppSight.io](https://www.appsight.io/app/bitmoji). No affiliation, I just found it.